# How to show all solutions for a particular recurrence solution

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

I've found that the recurrence relation $a_n = 4_{an−1} − 4a_{n−2} + (n + 1)2^n$ has the solution of $an = 2^n(p_0 + p_1n + n^2 + n^3/6)$.  I'm just trying to understand the steps necessary to solve that in this particular example, so I understand for future problems.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $$a_n = 4 a_{n-1} - 4 a_{n-2} + (n+1) 2^n$$
Let us first divide by $2^n$. We then get that
$$\dfrac{a_n}{2^n} = \dfrac42 \cdot \dfrac{a_{n-1}}{2^{n-1}} - \dfrac4{2^2} \cdot \dfrac{a_{n-2}}{2^{n-2}} + (n+1) \tag{$\star$}$$
Now let us call $\dfrac{a_n}{2^n}$ as $b_n$. Then $(\star)$ becomes
$$b_n = 2 b_{n-1} - b_{n-2} + (n+1) \implies (b_n - b_{n-1}) = (b_{n-1} - b_{n-2}) + (n+1) \tag{$\perp$}$$
Calling $b_n - b_{n-1} = c_n$, we get that $(\perp)$ becomes
$$c_n = c_{n-1} + (n+1) \tag{$\dagger$}$$
We have
$$c_n = c_{n-1} + (n+1) = c_{n-2} + n + (n+1) = c_{n-3} + (n-1) + n + (n+1)$$
Proceeding like this, we get that
$$c_n = c_0 + 2 + 3 + 4 + \cdots + n + (n+1) = c_0 - 1 + \dfrac{(n+1)(n+2)}2 = c_0 + \dfrac{n(n+3)}2$$
This gives that
$$b_n - b_{n-1} = c_0 + \dfrac{n(n+3)}2$$ Again by telescoping we get that
$$b_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \left(c_0 + \dfrac{k(k+3)}2 \right) + b_0 = b_0 + c_0 n + \dfrac{n(n+1)(n+5)}6 = p_0 + p_1n + n^2 + \dfrac{n^3}6$$
Now $$a_ n =2^n b_n = 2^n \left(p_0 + p_1n + n^2 + \dfrac{n^3}6\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $L$ denote the left-shift operator on sequences. That is, if $a$ is a sequence, then $La$ is a new sequence, whose $n^\text{th}$ term is given by $(La)_n=a_{n+1}$. We define the sum of two opersators on sequences $S$ and $T$ by pointwise addition, $[(S+T)a]_n=(Sa)_n+(Ta)_n$, and we define multiplication by composition, $(STa)_n=[S(Ta)]_n$. This means that polynomials in $L$ are also operators, and the usual rules of polynomial manipulation apply.

The original equation can be written in the form $a_{n+2}-4a_{n+1}+4a_n=(n+3)2^{n+2}$, which in terms of the $L$ operator is
$$
(L^2a)_n-4(La)_n+4a_n=(n+3)2^{n+2}\implies (L-2)^2a=4(n+3)2^n.\tag1
$$
We want to modify this so it is homogeneous. Since the non-homogeneous part, $f(n):=4(n+3)2^n$, is a polynomial of degree $1$ times $2^n$, it follows that $f(x)$ is annhilated by the operator $(L-2)^2$. Applying $(L-2)^2$ to both sides of $(3)$, we get
$$
(L-2)^4a=0\tag2
$$
First, we find the general solution to $(2)$. Since the polynomial in $L$ applied to $a$ has a quadruple root of $2$, the general solution is

$$
a_n=(C_0+C_1n+C_2n^2+C_3n^3)2^n\tag3
$$
for some constants $C_0,C_1,C_2,C_3$. Finally, we substitute the above formula for $a_n$ into the original equation, in order to derive the constraints on $a_n$.
$$
\begin{array}{l}
(C_0+C_1n+C_2n^2+C_3n^3)2^{n}\\
-4(C_0+C_1(n-1)+C_2(n-1)^2+C_3(n-1)^3)2^{n-1}\\
+4(C_0+C_1(n-2)+C_2(n-2)^2+C_3(n-2)^3)2^{n-2}
\end{array}
=(n+1)2^n
$$
After some effort, we can simplify the LHS to be a linear combination of $2^n$ and $n2^n$. The result is
$$
(2C_2-6C_3)2^n+(6C_3)n2^n=1\cdot 2^n+n\cdot 2^n
$$
Since $2^n$ and $n2^n$ are linearly independent as sequences, we can equate the coefficients above to get the system of equations
$$
\begin{align}
2C_2-6C_3&=1\\
6C_3&=1
\end{align}
$$
The solution is $C_2=1$ and $C_3=1/6$. Combining this with $(3)$, we conclude that the general solution is $(C_0+C_1n+n^2+n^3/6)2^n$.