# Help solving a non-homogenous recurrence relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I'm given the following recurrence relation:
$a_n = 4a_{n-1} - 4a_{n-2} + (n+1)2^n$.
I've solved it using generating functions, and am supposed to use characteristic equations to solve it. I know that the characteristic root is 2, so my "guessed" solution must be $n^2(An+B)2^n$.
I've plugged this into my relation, but have no idea how to proceed from here.
As far as I can tell, I'll be left with a single $An^3$ term, along with a constant term. Therefore, I can't solve it by equating coefficients, and nor can I solve it by setting the equation to 0.
Am I missing something? I've looked at other questions on here, and I can't figure out how to do the transformations some of them suggest. I'd prefer a solution that is more in line with the method I tried to use.
Thanks!

Comment: Hi. You can. Write it down, or look at it carefully. You'll see then $n^3$ and $n^2$ already cancel out, whatever $A$ and $B$ might be. That hints at how good your "guess" is.

Comment: @ClaudeChaunier as far as I can tell only the third order terms in my RHS cancel out, which still leaves one in my LHS

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to show all solutions for a particular recurrence solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/364171/how-to-show-all-solutions-for-a-particular-recurrence-solution) See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/779899

Comment: @ArmaanShah, you probably made a mistake, maybe forgetting to decrease $n$ in $2^n$ when writing down $a_{n-1} = (n-1)^2(A(n-1)+B)2^{n-1}$ and $a_{n-2} = (n-2)^2(A(n-2)+B)2^{n-2}$. Have some faith and some doubt !

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\;\;
\require{cancel}
\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{2^{n+1}} - \dfrac{a_n}{2^n} = \left(2\dfrac{a_{n}}{2^n} - \dfrac{a_{n-1}}{2^{n-1}} + \cancel{n}+2\right) - \left(2\dfrac{a_{n-1}}{2^{n-1}} - \dfrac{a_{n-2}}{2^{n-2}} + \cancel{n} +1\right)
\;\;$ is a linear recurrence for $\,b_n = \dfrac{a_n}{2^n}\,$.

Comment: I'm not quite getting this, could you elaborate please? Is the point of this to remove the $2^n$ term from the non-homogenous part? How would I apply it to the relation I've been given?

Comment: @ArmaanShah You get the recurrence $\,b_{n+1} = 3b_n - 3b_{n-1} + b_{n-2} + 1\,$ after regrouping and collecting the terms. Solve it for $\,b_n\,$ then reverse the substitution for $\,a_n = 2^n \cdot b_n\,$.

Comment: Where did you get your LHS from? Was it arbitrary, ie, from a pattern you recognized, or algebraic manipulation from the original equation?

Comment: @ArmaanShah Divide the given relation by $2^n$ to "incorporate" the exponential into the recurrence: $$a_n = 4a_{n-1} - 4a_{n-2} + (n+1)2^n \iff \frac{a_n}{2^n}= \frac{4}{2} \cdot\frac{a_{n-1}}{2^{n-1}} - \frac{4}{4}\cdot\frac{a_{n-2}}{2^{n-2}} + n +1$$
Write it for $n$ and $n+1$ then subtract to cancel out the $n$ term, which reduces it to a linear recurrence with constant coefficients.